ADF pipeline copied everything but stuck at the end
I ran 50 runs and 5 times happened that all data was loaded in the target table but the run never ended (ended on time out). Other 45 runs were OK.
It's running on Self-hosted IR.
Source: CSV in storage account
Target: Databricks SQL Warehouse
Any idea why it'd get stuck at the end?

Activity output:
{
"dataRead": 6863181402,
"dataWritten": 12575809624,
"filesRead": 1,
"sourcePeakConnections": 10,
"sinkPeakConnections": 11,
"rowsRead": 4162299,
"rowsCopied": 4162299,
"copyDuration": 7091,
"throughput": 968.829,
"errors": [],
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "IRName",
"usedParallelCopies": 10,
"executionDetails": [
    {
        "source": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
            "region": "West Europe"
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "Odbc"
        },
        "status": "Canceled",
        "start": "4/20/2024, 10:05:54 AM",
        "duration": 7091,
        "usedParallelCopies": 10,
        "profile": {
            "queue": {
                "status": "Completed",
                "duration": 3
            },
            "preCopyScript": {
                "status": "Completed",
                "duration": 4
            },
            "transfer": {
                "status": "InProgress",
                "duration": 7083,
                "details": {
                    "listingSource": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                        "workingDuration": 0
                    },
                    "readingFromSource": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                        "workingDuration": 493
                    },
                    "writingToSink": {
                        "type": "Odbc"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "detailedDurations": {
            "queuingDuration": 3,
            "preCopyScriptDuration": 4,
            "transferDuration": 7084
        }
    }
],
"dataConsistencyVerification": {
    "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
},
"durationInQueue": {
    "integrationRuntimeQueue": 3
}}


Could you please provide your pipeline output?

@Bhavani - I provided activity output.
